# basic idea to implement contour plotting of image

Tags: c++, python, image-processing, contour

I've been using `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` to plot the contour of images, and I wonder how to implement the contour plotting, but I found that the code of `pyplot.contour` hard for me to understand. I have this idea that, for a grayscale image, each pixel has an intensity value, to plot its contour, I might choose a set of intensity values, like partition the range `[min-intensity-value, max-intensity-value]` to 10 segments `[min-intensity-value, val0, val1,..., val8, max-intensity-value]`, then for each segment's boundary intensity value (like `val0, val1,...,val8`), find out all those pixels which has the same intensity value, and I think those pixels will form a contour line.

Is my idea a right way to go? Hope anyone can give me a basic idea about how to implement it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of connecting all values with the same colour won't work, as there is no guarantee that these are connected. Also, consider e.g. the case of two equal-coloured pixels touching at the corner: There is no way to say whether these are connected or e.g. the other diagonal.

I believe the question is basically what you want to achieve. If you just want to vectorize the image, there are existing tools for that, like e.g. [POtrace](http://potrace.sf.net). If you need something special or have special input data, then you will get better results when you tell people about this. In that case, I would also take an hour or two to look up the very good description for the POtrace algorithm from their website, maybe you can borrow a few good ideas from it?